# Multiple plots of multple ODEs in a single graph using Plotly

Tags: python, scipy, plotly, ode, odeint

I'm trying to include two or more than two plots of differential equations(Scipy.integrate package ODEINT) using Plotly but yet it plots only the initial points instead of the whole plots. [Here is the corresponding output image[I'm tryin to reproduce the plots made in Matplot which is quite trivial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFQyk.png)Here is the whole code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
#import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as G 


# initial condition
y0 = 5.0


# time points
t = np.arange(0,20,1)


# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t,k):
    dydt = -k * y
    return dydt



# solve ODEs
k = 0.1
y1 = odeint(model,y0,t,args=(k,))
k = 0.2
y2 = odeint(model,y0,t,args=(k,))
k = 0.5
y3 = odeint(model,y0,t,args=(k,))

fig = G.Figure()

#rows, cols = (3, 20) 
#y = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)] 

for r in [y1, y2, y3]:
    fig.add_trace(G.Scatter(
        x=t,        
        y=r
        )
    )
     
    
fig.update_layout(title='Sample Graph',
                  xaxis_title='time',
                  yaxis_title='y',
                  template='plotly_white')

# Display figure
fig.show() 
plot(fig)
```

Comment: I've already used general exponential(Mathematical) expressions and this code works fine for them, but I only face problem when I do a function call, such as this.

Answer (score 1):

If you flatten the three arrays (`y1`, `y2`, `y3`) your code will work as it is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as G

# initial condition
y0 = 5.0

# time points
t = np.arange(0, 20, 1)

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y, t, k):
    dydt = -k * y
    return dydt

# solve ODEs
k = 0.1
y1 = odeint(model, y0, t, args=(k,)).flatten()

k = 0.2
y2 = odeint(model, y0, t, args=(k,)).flatten()

k = 0.5
y3 = odeint(model, y0, t, args=(k,)).flatten()

fig = G.Figure()

for r in [y1, y2, y3]:
    fig.add_trace(G.Scatter(
        x=t,
        y=r
    ))

fig.update_layout(title='Sample Graph',
                  xaxis_title='time',
                  yaxis_title='y',
                  template='plotly_white')

# display figure
fig.show()
```

Comment: @user14295847 : Or explicitly select the solution component, `y1 = y1[:,0]`. If the state vector has more than one component, `.flatten()` could lead to unexpected errors.